# Understanding callback on this MDN example

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async.js

The code comes from an [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Displaying_data/Home_page) on how to use Node.js and mongoose. The idea is to make parallel request to get the count of documents in different models. I don't understand where the callback passed to each async.parallel comes from, where it is defined and what it does, it seems like a dummy function to me. Could you help me understand it? Here is the code:

```
var Book = require('../models/book');
var Author = require('../models/author');
var Genre = require('../models/genre');
var BookInstance = require('../models/bookinstance');

var async = require('async');

exports.index = function(req, res) {

    async.parallel({
        book_count: function(callback) {
            Book.countDocuments({}, callback); // Pass an empty object as match condition to find all documents of this collection
        },
        book_instance_count: function(callback) {
            BookInstance.countDocuments({}, callback);
        },
        book_instance_available_count: function(callback) {
            BookInstance.countDocuments({status:'Available'}, callback);
        },
        author_count: function(callback) {
            Author.countDocuments({}, callback);
        },
        genre_count: function(callback) {
            Genre.countDocuments({}, callback);
        }
    }, function(err, results) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Local Library Home', error: err, data: results });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the callback is passed by the async package.

Explanation:

As async parallel function takes array or object (in your example) of asynchronous tasks and these async tasks require a callback which will get called when its execution completes or if there is an error. So parallel function provides these callback functions and will call your callback ( provided as a second parameter to parallel function call) when all of them are called or got an error in any of them.

You can check the detailed explanation from here - https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#parallel

Update:

Consider parallel as a wrapper function like:

```
function parallel(tasks, userCallback) {
    let tasksDone = [];
    function callback(err, data){ // this is the callback function you're asking for
        if(err){
            userCallback(err); // calling callback in case of error
        }else {
            tasksDone.push(data);
            if(tasks.length === tasksDone.length){
                userCallback(null, tasksDone); // calling callback when all the tasks finished
            }
        }
    }

    tasks.forEach(task => {
        task(callback); // calling each task without waiting for previous one to finish 
    })
}
```

Note: This is not a proper implementation of parallel function of async, this is just an example to understand how we can use callback function internally and what is its usecase

Comment: Thanks for your help!. Let me ask, then, where is "callback" defined? and what's its use besides letting know that the asynchronous task has finished? Is the internal behavior of "callback" defined by async (since I can't see error handling logic, nor next, nor results)?

Comment: In other words, who is passing the argument "callback" to each task, and how or where is that argument defined?

Comment: @Mariano check the updated answer, i've added an example

Comment: Thank you @Abhay!! No it is much more clear! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome :). Please accept this answer, so it'll be helpful to others as well.

Comment: I can't, I have 13 in reputation. I think that If you vote up my question I'll get 15 rep. and I can do it!